# Java For Loop Inside Constructor is Infinitely Repeating

Tags: java, constructor, for-loop, repeat, infinite

So, for some reason when I try to use a for loop to initialize panels in chess board, it actually loops the loop itself. In other words, it doesn't go on forever, but it starts and completes again and again.

```
package chessgame;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class ChessGame extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

    public static final int WIDTH=800;
    public static final int HEIGHT=800;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ChessGame gui = new ChessGame();
        gui.setVisible(true);
    }
    public ChessGame(){
        super("Chess Game Demo");
        setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new GridLayout(8,8));
        JPanel[] chessSquares = new JPanel[64];
        for (int a=0;a<64;a++){
            System.out.println(a);
        }
    }
}
```

I have included all potentially relevant code because I plan to use indices of chessSquares to color squares black and white. When I do this I also get a NullPointerException. I can understand why I'm getting that given the following error, but I cannot at all understand why a would be printed 0, 1....62, 63 over and over again. I am relatively new to Swing and have absolutely no idea why it does this. If anyone could explain that would be tremendously helpful. Thanks.

Comment: That code doesn't exhibit the behavior you described. You've apparently cut out the part that does. (Also, it won't compile unless you remove the `implements ActionListener`.)

Comment: My guess is that you have some code calling `new ChessGame();` in a loop. Why don't you break in with a debugger to see what's going on?

Comment: After adding an empty public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) method, mine worked.  Output was from 0 to 63

Comment: Yeah, I've just realized that I declare an array of objects of class ChessGame. It doesn't actually infinitely loop, but it takes a good 30 seconds to end.  The answer here I guess is too just making the no-argument constructor for the window into one with an unused parameter to differentiate the two. Thanks Gabe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't put meaningful initialization in `ChessGame`'s constructor, but instead override `frameInit`.  When you do, also be sure to call `super.frameInit()`.  See the [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#frameInit%28%29) or [this tutorial](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/ExtendingJFrameClosingFramesbyDefault.htm).